# how to block initial cached state in Rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

My issue is that I want to redirect the user to another route when a query results in an error. The first time the query is run, it works, because nothing is cached, but if a user tries again, the cached error state appears before the new fetch.

```
  const {
    data: device,
    isFetching,
    error,
    isLoading,
    isError
  } = useGetDeviceQuery(id, {
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true
  });

  console.log(isLoading, isFetching, error);

  if (error && !isFetching) {
    return <Navigate to="/devices" replace/>
  }
```

It only works on the first error, as isFetching starts as true, but if I try again, is fetching starts as false along with the first fetch error, so even if there is no error now, the app will redirect.

Just for some concept i have these two images of console logs from isFetching.
.First query:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VSEH.png)

.Second query:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmhJ8.png)